# Extension Methods in Xamarin Workbooks

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I've recently started playing around with [Xamarin Workbooks](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/workbooks/) and would like to use it to provide API documentation for some of the things I'm working on.

In one of my first tests however it appears that I can't use extension methods that I've imported via [a `Nuget` package that I created specifically to test this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Red.Data/). I can navigate through the namespaces and types provided in the nuget package and call the methods the static way. But not the way I intended; as extension methods.

Is this a bug or missing feature and can I apply a workaround for it in my workbook?

Answer (score 1):

when pasting a static extension class in a workbook and running it, it says `error CS1109: Extension methods must be defined in a top level static class; MyExtensions is a nested class`

I've noticed that writing (only) the extension methods (so not contained in a static class) directly at the root of a workbook works.

I'm guessing the whole workbook is some sort of a static class itself

[image]

Comment: it also has to be defined above the code that is using it